# Django CSS HTML Not Applying

Tags: html, css, django

I am new to Django and am currently trying to customize the aesthetics of my polling app. I cannot get my style sheet to apply to my polling app. Specifically, I am looking to change the fonts/color of the questions/h1 tag as well as adding in a background image.

The background remains white, and the links do not reflect the style.css file. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

polls/style.css

```
li a {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

body {
    padding-left: 150px;
    background-image: url('C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price 
Tracking\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\images\sample123.jpg');
}
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Polling</title>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1><a href='https://www.google.com'>Welcome to the polling app!</a></h1>
    </div>

<!-- Question List -->

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Loaded Code

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Polling</title>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1><a href='https://www.google.com'>Welcome to the polling app!</a></h1>
    </div>

<!-- Question List -->


    <ul>
    
        <li><a href="/polls/3/">Where is your home office?</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/polls/2/">What&#x27;s your Enterprise ID?</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/polls/1/">What&#x27;s up?</a></li>
    
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i suggest , after the page load press `ctrl+u` and see is styles loaded correctly? if they are loaded , the problem is the styles itself

Comment: Are you placing your styles.css in the static folder? If not please take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yes, the file is in C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls

Comment: @meti - I added in the results from hitting CTRL-U. It looks like everything is loading?

Comment: please press `ctrl+shift+i` then  in console tab see any errors accured or not?

Comment: Screenshot added of the console tab - no apparent errors

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, following are the changes I made to get it working

Copy your background image and style.css in your static/polls/ directory

Add this line at the top of your settings.py

```
import os
```

Add this line at the bottom of your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

index.html looks like this

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Polling</title>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "polls/style.css" %}">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1><a href="https://www.google.com">Welcome to the polling app!</a></h1>
    </div>

<!-- Question List -->

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

style.css looks like this (repeat does not work, so I removed it. By default image repeats itself but if you don't want it to repeat use background-size: cover;)

```
li a {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

body {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-image: url('Wallpaper.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I've added all of that code into settings.py and am still not seeing the correct results... all code and screenshots updated based on these edits. Thoughts?

Comment: Change 
`background-image: url('C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price 
Tracking\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\images\sample123.jpg');`
to
`background-image: url('images\sample123.jpg'); `